# JPA Hibernate JPQL VALUE of Map<key, value> - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am using JPA and Hibernate 4.3.1 as the JPA provider. I am using JPQL to write my queries. When I write a JPQL to fetch values from an Entity which has a Map referencing another table, it is failing.
Below is my POJO:

```
public class Book {  

    @Id  
    @Column(name="ID", updatable=false, unique=true)
    private String id;  

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name="language")
    @Column(name="text")
    @CollectionTable(name = "BOOK_TITLES")
    private Map<String, String> title = Collections.emptyMap();

    // other fields
}
```

I need to fetch all books whose title is a particular value. A Book can have title in multiple languages. Hence for one Book ID, there can be multiple records in the BOOK_TITLES table. Below is the JPQL:

```
SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE value(b.t) IN :title
```

But the HQL that gets formed for this results in the subquery returning more than 1 row:

```
select book0_.ID as ID1_0_, ...<other fields>
from my_library.BOOKS book0_ cross join my_library.BOOK_TITLES title1_
where book0_.ID=title1_.Book_ID
and ((select title1_.TEXT from my_library.BOOK_TITLES title1_
      where book0_.ID=title1_.Book_ID) in (?))
```

This works fine if there is just 1 title for a book. But if there are more titles for one book, then this fails because the subquery returns more than 1 row.

I tried the solution in [StackOverflowQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263725/jpas-mapkey-value-query-by-jpql-failed) which talked about reversing the VALUE(m) = :value to :value IN VALUE(m). But this does not work for me and it says unexpected token ( found.

Is there a way to alter the JPQL such that my HQL gets formed as below: I do not want to use Criteria Builder.

```
select book0_.ID as ID1_0_, ...<other fields>  
from my_library.BOOKS book0_ cross join my_library.BOOK_TITLES title1_
where book0_.ID=title1_.Book_ID and title1_.TEXT IN (?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inverting VALUE and :value and adding parenthesis should work. Ex:

```
@Query("select t from Object t join t.names n where :name IN (VALUE(n.map))")
```