# spring data sort by map-value within a given key

Tags: jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I would like to sort a Map of  by the value. For example I have **Person** class which has a map of **details** that are stored in a map with key-value `Map<String, String>`.

I am using springboot with hibernate5. This is the mapping.

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @DocumentId
    @Column(name = "personid")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    // this is a collection of person details
    @ElementCollection()
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "detailkey")
    @Column(name = "detailvalue")
    @CollectionTable(name = "details", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "personid"))
    Map<String, String> details = new HashMap<>();

    //getter and setters omitted
```

So far I am able to retrieve a person with some specific detailskey and specific detail value. So for example a person table in the DB has **eyecolor** as detail attribute and as value can have "**green**", "**blue**", "**brown**". Note this is not a real example, just for clarity purposes.

So for example I can get the list of persons and sort them by their name, in the controller I can do

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "name");
```

and the opposite direction

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "name");
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(1, 10, sort);
pageResult = personRepository.findAll(
            "eyecolor", "green", pageable
        );
```

and this one will return the list of persons that have "eyecolor" as green. So far so good and this is working as expected. Now I would like to define a sorting on the detailvalue.

For example I would like to get a list of person sorted by their eyecolor. So first I should have the persons that have "**blue**", "**brown**", "**green**".

how can the Sort be specified in this case ?

In standard SQL it would be something like this:

SELECT p.* from persons p LEFT JOIN details d ON
  p.personid = d.personid AND p.detailkey='eyercolor' ORDER BY 
  p.detailvalue ASC;

Answer (score 1):

The following query worked for me:

```
SELECT p FROM Person p JOIN p.details d WHERE KEY(d) = 'eyecolor' ORDER BY d
```

(note that `ORDER BY VALUE(d)` would fail since `VALUE(d)` still seems to behave as described here: [JPA's Map<KEY, VALUE> query by JPQL failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263725/jpas-mapkey-value-query-by-jpql-failed))

Now, I'm not particularly well versed with Spring Data, but I suppose you should be able to use the above query (without the `ORDER BY` part) with the `@Query` annotation on your `PersonRepository.findAll` method (I'm assuming that's a custom method) and provide the sorting using `JpaSort.unsafe("d")`.